# Writing to a MIDI port in Python and Mac Lion

Tags: python, macos, midi

Now it's been like 3 days and I still don't manage. Maybe someone can help.

I want to send a control command to a midi device, via python, on a mac. Everywhere I see, the happy answer is to use pygame, but truth is that the pygame version on the mac lacks that functionality.

When I try run this two lines :

```
from pygame import midi
midi.init()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "midi_send.py", line 9, in <module>
midi.init()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/pygame/midi.py", line 71, in init
import pygame.pypm
ImportError: No module named pypm
```

I've looked and looked and all I find is dead ends.

Has anyone actually tried using pygame to write to a midiport, on a mac? is there an alternative that doesn't include getting stuck in some gcc compile error something replace line N of somemidi.o file somewhere in /etc/whatever/whatever?

Sorry for being frustrated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [rtmidi-python](https://github.com/superquadratic/rtmidi-python) library (or older and slightly different [pyrtmidi](https://github.com/tedr56/PyRtMidi)) - both based on [rtmidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) which provides for straightforward sending of MIDI Control and Notes:

```
import rtmidi_python as rtmidi

midi_out = rtmidi.MidiOut()
midi_out.open_port(0)

midi_out.send_message([0x90, 48, 100]) # Note on
midi_out.send_message([0x80, 48, 100]) # Note off
```